# How to listen only 443 in nginx server

Tags: nginx, server, digital-ocean

I am using node.js project in a nginx digital ocean server.

I have configured the server with reverse proxy to the node project. All works great. But my socket doesn't work. It seems 80 and 443 problems.

I tried to do this bellow configuration in my server

```
    server {
    root /home/sadek/project/node;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8181;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


   }
   server {
    if ($host = www.domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 443 ssl;
        server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


     }
```

But I get this error `conflicting server name "domain.com" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored`

Thank you.

Comment: Two `server` blocks with the same server name and port in your configuration. Definite problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    server {
        listen 443 ;
        server_name abc.com www.abc.com;
        large_client_header_buffers 8 32k;
  if ($http_user_agent ~* Googlebot) {  
    return 403; 
  }
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_pass https://localhost:8181;
                proxy_read_timeout 90;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_buffers 8 32k;
                proxy_buffer_size 64k;
        }
}
```

Comment: Should I replace all the other part and use this one only>

Comment: replace all the parts.